# Minecraft Launcher won't open at all

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I have attempted to run the Minecraft launcher several times but it won't respond at all. It has previously worked just fine on this machine, the only thing different is that my OS (Windows 10) recently updated, and this is the first time I have attempted to run it since then.

I have tried to troubleshoot it in several ways, I have *erased the `profiles.json`* file in `.minecraft`, to no avail. Then, I tried updating Java. When that failed, I tried running the game in compatibility mode. As a last resort, I went nuclear and completely wiped any Minecraft files in my computer.

All other threads I've found tell me to do one of the above, and it'll work, the rest say that it has something to do with a faulty driver, but considering Minecraft is the only thing not working (And I do run a load of games and graphics design programs), I'm a bit skeptical that it's *that*. After all of those attempts I'm getting a bit worried that it's something related to that fateful Windows update, as they all seem to break something when they happen and unfortunately can't be toggled off (If someone can show me the way to permanently disable those too, I'd be grateful)

Some more system information:

- Windows 10 Pro 64x
- GEforce GTX 1050 TI
- Asus B85 Pro Gamer
- Intel Core I7 4770 8x @3.4ghz
- 16GB RAM

Edit: More information, as requested.
It's not that the launcher crashes upon executing, it simply won't be executed or opened at all, without any new windows being opened, any error messages, crash logs or new processes in the Task Manager. All I get as a feedback is **a split second of the mouse loading animation**. I have been told to look through the crash logs, but since I did a fresh install while removing all Minecraft related folders and files from my computer, there doesn't exist a .minecraft directory where the crash logs are being generated.
I have also attempted to utilize the [alternative launcher](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/alternative), as indicated by another user, as provided in Mojang's website. I run in exactly the same problem: Nothing is opened, I get no new processes, and there are no crash logs. I attempted to execute it with administrator privileges turned on, as well as through the command prompt directly, to no avail. I get the same feedback as trying to open the default launcher, a split second of the mouse loading animation.

Comment: Have you tried checking if there is a log file being created by the launcher? If so, it might contain helpful information. https://minecrafthopper.net/help/guides/getting-minecraft-launcher-log/

Comment: @AJPerez I did not, but after a fresh reinstall, .minecraft doesn't even exist, and I can't make it exist because the launcher won't open and create those files.

I should clarify - the launcher doesn't crash, because it doesn't open *at all*. It won't get executed no matter what I do. I tried opening it through the shortcut, I tried opening it directly in the install folder, I tried running it as an administrator, I even tried executing the .exe file through command prompt, the launcher simply won't open *at all*.

Comment: That's also useful info that probably should be edited into your question. There is a difference between "it crashes before showing any window" and "the process doesn't even start". Now we know which one it is. Sadly that's where my knowledge of Java Minecraft ends, but I hope somebody else will be able to help you

Comment: At this point I'm just googling, which you clearly have done yourself. But... have you tried the alternative launcher? https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360046297751-Minecraft-Launcher-Failure-

Comment: can you attempt to run it as an administrator, and then check Task Manager for the Minecraft Launcher process? if possible, can you copy your entire `.minecraft` folder to a new computer, and see if the game launches from there? preferably on the same version of Windows as your current.

Comment: @EarthToAccess I did attempt running it as an administrator, and as I pointed out in the original post, I also don't see any new processes in Task Manager. There isn't a .minecraft folder to transfer to another computer, as the launcher won't run to create that folder. I don't think trying to run the launcher in another computer will bring any productive results, as it is the same .msi/.exe as the one available on Minecraft's website.

Comment: like i said, try to *copy* your entire `.minecraft` folder from the computer with the issue to a new computer. then, re-install the launcher to the second system. you should also still try just a fresh install of Minecraft on the new system too. this will rule out whether it's a problem with your specific computer, or the launcher files.

Comment: You said that your OS recently updated, you could try and uninstall the latest windows update. This is sometimes the problem.

Comment: If it is not working on the alternative launcher, that probably indicates a problem with the .minecraft folder, as both launchers are completely different.

Comment: Did you try deleting the %appdata% minecraft folder entirely to get a fresh .minecraft folder?

Comment: have you tried getting the new launcher, no matter how much people hate it?

Comment: I have read online it might be good to update graphics drivers. Have you done this already?

Comment: Are you using the microsoft store launcher?

Comment: I know this is a kinda stupid question but have you reinstalled? EDIT nvm just read comments

Comment: I've also had a similar problem. The thing is, I was on a very old PC when I tried before. Said very old PC was also running the old launcher and also crashed when I tried to install the new one

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall the launcher, or install the newest version of Java JRE.

Comment: I believe the OP already did both things before posting their question

Comment: @AJPerez possible

Comment: Hi AnarLezzMC, welcome to Arqade! As mentioned in the question, it appears the asker already tried those two things. Are there any other troubleshooting steps that you would recommend? You can edit your answer to add additional troubleshooting steps.

Comment: In my experienced, Minecraft won't run with anything but Java 8. That being said, I don't know much about Minecraft on Windows, so that's about as much help as I can provide.